# Can torrent search engine is work like regular search engine

Tags: search-engine, web-crawler, bittorrent

Regular search engine like google,yahoo and msn etc. I make also a search engine for software. First of all it get the all pages of site and then required data.Can this is also work in torrent sites or something else. For my search engine it is essential that torrent link must be present in anywhere of the site  which has to be under crawling.

Answer (score 0):

this works for most public sites.. but private sites have no robot access.  You can find alot of examples of torrent search engines on google